# Bad encoding with WWW::Mechanize in Perl

Tags: perl, character-encoding, mechanize

I'm trying to post content through a website with [`WWW:Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3aMechanize).

My content seems to be UTF-8 and the website where I post it is a page that specifies ISO-8859-15 encoding on the head of the HTML page.

The post works but I get this result

Example of the encoding I have (in French) :

```
acteur majeur de l?assurance et
rÃ©fÃ©rence en gestion
patrimoniale, propose une approche globale pour
une clientÃ¨le aisÃ©e et haut de gamme.
```

Here is my code

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Encode;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
   stack_depth => 0,
   timeout => 10,
);

mech->get($urlContentOtherWebsite);
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($mech->content); 
my $content = $tree->findvalue('/html/body//div[@id="content"]');
$tree->delete;
mech->get($urlFormMyWebsite);
$mech->form_name("formular"); # Form Post Emploi
$mech->set_fields(
  content => $content
);
$mech->submit;
```

have you some idea or clue to resolve my problem please?

Answer (score 3):

From studying the code:
[HTML::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aForm), which is used inside [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize), uses the `accept-charset` parameter of the `<form...>` tag to find out which encoding to use. If there is no such parameter than it uses a default charset, which is UTF-8.  You can set the acceptable charset with `$form->accept_charset('iso-8859-1')`, e.g. the following should work if I read the code correctly:

```
$mech->form_name("formular")->accept_charset('iso-8859-1');
$mech->set_fields(...);
$mech->submit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)';
```

at the start of your program to declare that `STDOUT` is expecting UTF-8 characters, otherwise you will see the individual bytes instead of the proper characters

You also need to decode the input as UTF-8 using

```
use Encode;
```

followed by

```
decode('UTF-8', $_)
```

where the incoming text is in `$_`.

Here's an example

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode;

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)';

print decode('UTF-8', $_) for <DATA>;

__DATA__
acteur majeur de l?assurance et
rÃ©fÃ©rence en gestion
patrimoniale, propose une approche globale pour
une clientÃ¨le aisÃ©e et haut de gamme.
```

**output**

```
acteur majeur de l?assurance et
référence en gestion
patrimoniale, propose une approche globale pour
une clientèle aisée et haut de gamme.
```

I don't quite understand `l?assurance`, but I imagine that the data has been altered somewhere between the original web site and the Stack Overflow post. As you can see, the rest of the text is correct

Comment: I hope the downvoter will explain themselves? I don't see anything wrong but I don't want to post misleading information

Comment: +1 Note that OP's code has `use open qw(:std :utf8);`

Comment: The question mark most likely refers to [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK ’](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2019). See [Coverage of punctuation signs and apostrophes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15#Coverage_of_punctuation_signs_and_apostrophes): "**For some languages listed above, the correct typographical quotation marks are missing, since only «, », ", and ' are included.**"